# uninitialized constant Logger::SimpleFormatter (NameError) after upgrading rails to 6.1.0 and ruby 2.7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Tried by including require 'logger', require 'active_support/logger' in application.rb file.

error:
/config/application.rb:64:in `class:Application': uninitialized constant Logger::SimpleFormatter (NameError)
Did you mean?  SimpleDelegator

Comment: Did you do a `bundle install` after your upgrade to a new ruby version? Or maybe your gem was installed globally for your ruby `< 2.7` install?

Comment: Yup I did bundle install after the upgradation

Comment: gem is not installed globally

Answer (score 1):

[`Logger::SimpleFormatter`](https://apidock.com/rails/Logger/SimpleFormatter) was deprecated in rails 4.0, and [removed in rails 4.1](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/4_1_release_notes.html#active-support-removals).

You can use `ActiveSupport::Logger::SimpleFormatter` instead.

As a general rule, you should never attempt such a large upgrade (`v4.0.x --> v6.1.0`?!) in one big leap; there are probably countless other errors. Try to go one minor version at a time, and fix deprecations along the way.